# How do I add a downloaded system image to android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-x86

I have downloaded the KitKat system image from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sysimg_x86-19_r20.zip) but cannot figure out where to extract it to.

Comment: Why don't you download that system image using Android Studio tool?

Comment: I have a slow connection and need to pause often

Comment: What operating system are you using?